# ¿Cómo convierto un JsonConvert.SerializeObject en un array?

Tags: javascript, c#, json

Del lado backend C# obtengo la información de la siguiente manera:

```
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(details);
```

Donde "details" es un array de entidades. El resultado es el siguiente:

```
'[{"mercadoDescriptions":null,"productDescriptions":"|BELLAFEM PLENITUD CON 120 MG DE ISOFLAVONAS AL DÍA. LA ÚNICA DOSIS COMPROBADA QUE REDUCE LA PÉRDIDA DE DENSIDAD MINERAL ÓSEA Y BRINDA UN CONTROL ÓPTIMO DE LOS MOLESTOS BOCHORNOS Y MALOS|* 300 MG DE OMEGA 3, 250 MG DHA Y 50 MG EPA, L-METILFOLATO. CÁPSULAS PEQUEÑAS, CERTIFICADO DE CALIDAD.|* ABSORCIÓN FISIOLÓGICA Y SIN EFECTOS SECUNDARIOS DEL HIERRO ORAL SOLIDO, EL ANTIANÉMICO LÍQUIDO PARA CUALQUIER MIEMBRO DE LA FAMILIA","Id":33431717,"PeriodCode":1251,"Unidades":2,"AuditSaleCode":124,"LegacyCode":2922777,"Producto":"CALCIO+VIT,D,GI","Mercado":"2 VIPLENA & BELLAFEM PLENITUD","MercadoColumn":"1","MercadoComment":null,"ProductComment":"2|1|3",},{"mercadoDescriptions":null,"productDescriptions":"|BELLAFEM PLENITUD CON 120 MG DE ISOFLAVONAS AL DÍA. LA ÚNICA DOSIS COMPROBADA QUE REDUCE LA PÉRDIDA DE DENSIDAD MINERAL ÓSEA Y BRINDA UN CONTROL ÓPTIMO DE LOS MOLESTOS BOCHORNOS Y MALOS|* 300 MG DE OMEGA 3, 250 MG DHA Y 50 MG EPA, L-METILFOLATO. CÁPSULAS PEQUEÑAS, CERTIFICADO DE CALIDAD.|* ABSORCIÓN FISIOLÓGICA Y SIN EFECTOS SECUNDARIOS DEL HIERRO ORAL SOLIDO, EL ANTIANÉMICO LÍQUIDO PARA CUALQUIER MIEMBRO DE LA FAMILIA","Id":33431718,"PeriodCode":1251,"Unidades":14,"AuditSaleCode":124,"LegacyCode":2922777,"Producto":"EVEMGLEA","Mercado":"4 EVEMGLEA","MercadoColumn":"1","MercadoComment":null,"ProductComment":"2|1|3",},{"mercadoDescriptions":"|XANELLE EL ANTIMICÓTICO VAGINAL UNIDOSIS DE PRESCRIPCIÓN.","productDescriptions":"|BELLAFEM PLENITUD CON 120 MG DE ISOFLAVONAS AL DÍA. LA ÚNICA DOSIS COMPROBADA QUE REDUCE LA PÉRDIDA DE DENSIDAD MINERAL ÓSEA Y BRINDA UN CONTROL ÓPTIMO DE LOS MOLESTOS BOCHORNOS Y MALOS|* 300 MG DE OMEGA 3, 250 MG DHA Y 50 MG EPA, L-METILFOLATO. CÁPSULAS PEQUEÑAS, CERTIFICADO DE CALIDAD.|* ABSORCIÓN FISIOLÓGICA Y SIN EFECTOS SECUNDARIOS DEL HIERRO ORAL SOLIDO, EL ANTIANÉMICO LÍQUIDO PARA CUALQUIER MIEMBRO DE LA FAMILIA","Id":33431719,"PeriodCode":1251,"Unidades":2,"AuditSaleCode":124,"LegacyCode":2922777,"Producto":"SODIO","Mercado":"2 VIPLENA & BELLAFEM PLENITUD","MercadoColumn":"1","MercadoComment":"1","ProductComment":"2|1|3",},{"mercadoDescriptions":"|XANELLE EL ANTIMICÓTICO VAGINAL UNIDOSIS DE PRESCRIPCIÓN.","productDescriptions":"|BELLAFEM PLENITUD CON 120 MG DE ISOFLAVONAS AL DÍA. LA ÚNICA DOSIS COMPROBADA QUE REDUCE LA PÉRDIDA DE DENSIDAD MINERAL ÓSEA Y BRINDA UN CONTROL ÓPTIMO DE LOS MOLESTOS BOCHORNOS Y MALOS|* 300 MG DE OMEGA 3, 250 MG DHA Y 50 MG EPA, L-METILFOLATO. CÁPSULAS PEQUEÑAS, CERTIFICADO DE CALIDAD.|* ABSORCIÓN FISIOLÓGICA Y SIN EFECTOS SECUNDARIOS DEL HIERRO ORAL SOLIDO, EL ANTIANÉMICO LÍQUIDO PARA CUALQUIER MIEMBRO DE LA FAMILIA","Id":33427721,"PeriodCode":1251,"Unidades":3,"AuditSaleCode":124,"LegacyCode":2922777,"Producto":"CENTRUM GENDER","Mercado":"1 TRANSVITAL E","MercadoColumn":"1","MercadoComment":"1","ProductComment":"2|1|3",},{"mercadoDescriptions":"|XANELLE EL ANTIMICÓTICO VAGINAL UNIDOSIS DE PRESCRIPCIÓN.","productDescriptions":"|BELLAFEM PLENITUD CON 120 MG DE ISOFLAVONAS AL DÍA. LA ÚNICA DOSIS COMPROBADA QUE REDUCE LA PÉRDIDA DE DENSIDAD MINERAL ÓSEA Y BRINDA UN CONTROL ÓPTIMO DE LOS MOLESTOS BOCHORNOS Y MALOS|* 300 MG DE OMEGA 3, 250 MG DHA Y 50 MG EPA, L-METILFOLATO. CÁPSULAS PEQUEÑAS, CERTIFICADO DE CALIDAD.|* ABSORCIÓN FISIOLÓGICA Y SIN EFECTOS SECUNDARIOS DEL HIERRO ORAL SOLIDO, EL ANTIANÉMICO LÍQUIDO PARA CUALQUIER MIEMBRO DE LA FAMILIA","Id":33427722,"PeriodCode":1251,"Unidades":3,"AuditSaleCode":124,"LegacyCode":2922777,"Producto":"PHARMATON","Mercado":"1 TRANSVITAL E","MercadoColumn":"1","MercadoComment":"1","ProductComment":"2|1|3",},{"mercadoDescriptions":"|XANELLE EL ANTIMICÓTICO VAGINAL UNIDOSIS DE PRESCRIPCIÓN.","productDescriptions":"|BELLAFEM PLENITUD CON 120 MG DE ISOFLAVONAS AL DÍA. LA ÚNICA DOSIS COMPROBADA QUE REDUCE LA PÉRDIDA DE DENSIDAD MINERAL ÓSEA Y BRINDA UN CONTROL ÓPTIMO DE LOS MOLESTOS BOCHORNOS Y MALOS|* 300 MG DE OMEGA 3, 250 MG DHA Y 50 MG EPA, L-METILFOLATO. CÁPSULAS PEQUEÑAS, CERTIFICADO DE CALIDAD.|* ABSORCIÓN FISIOLÓGICA Y SIN EFECTOS SECUNDARIOS DEL HIERRO ORAL SOLIDO, EL ANTIANÉMICO LÍQUIDO PARA CUALQUIER MIEMBRO DE LA FAMILIA","Id":33427723,"PeriodCode":1251,"Unidades":4,"AuditSaleCode":124,"LegacyCode":2922777,"Producto":"HISTOFIL","Mercado":"2 MILDA","MercadoColumn":"1","MercadoComment":"1","ProductComment":"2|1|3",},{"mercadoDescriptions":"|XANELLE EL ANTIMICÓTICO VAGINAL UNIDOSIS DE PRESCRIPCIÓN.","productDescriptions":"|BELLAFEM PLENITUD CON 120 MG DE ISOFLAVONAS AL DÍA. LA ÚNICA DOSIS COMPROBADA QUE REDUCE LA PÉRDIDA DE DENSIDAD MINERAL ÓSEA Y BRINDA UN CONTROL ÓPTIMO DE LOS MOLESTOS BOCHORNOS Y MALOS|* 300 MG DE OMEGA 3, 250 MG DHA Y 50 MG EPA, L-METILFOLATO. CÁPSULAS PEQUEÑAS, CERTIFICADO DE CALIDAD.|* ABSORCIÓN FISIOLÓGICA Y SIN EFECTOS SECUNDARIOS DEL HIERRO ORAL SOLIDO, EL ANTIANÉMICO LÍQUIDO PARA CUALQUIER MIEMBRO DE LA FAMILIA","Id":33427724,"PeriodCode":1251,"Unidades":1,"AuditSaleCode":124,"LegacyCode":2922777,"Producto":"FOSFOCIL G,U,","Mercado":"3 FOSUNE","MercadoColumn":"1","MercadoComment":"1","ProductComment":"2|1|3",},{"mercadoDescriptions":"|XANELLE EL ANTIMICÓTICO VAGINAL UNIDOSIS DE PRESCRIPCIÓN.","productDescriptions":"|BELLAFEM PLENITUD CON 120 MG DE ISOFLAVONAS AL DÍA. LA ÚNICA DOSIS COMPROBADA QUE REDUCE LA PÉRDIDA DE DENSIDAD MINERAL ÓSEA Y BRINDA UN CONTROL ÓPTIMO DE LOS MOLESTOS BOCHORNOS Y MALOS|* 300 MG DE OMEGA 3, 250 MG DHA Y 50 MG EPA, L-METILFOLATO. CÁPSULAS PEQUEÑAS, CERTIFICADO DE CALIDAD.|* ABSORCIÓN FISIOLÓGICA Y SIN EFECTOS SECUNDARIOS DEL HIERRO ORAL SOLIDO, EL ANTIANÉMICO LÍQUIDO PARA CUALQUIER MIEMBRO DE LA FAMILIA","Id":33427725,"PeriodCode":1251,"Unidades":3,"AuditSaleCode":124,"LegacyCode":2922777,"Producto":"NITROFURANTOI,GI","Mercado":"3 FOSUNE","MercadoColumn":"2","MercadoComment":"1","ProductComment":"2|1|3",}]'
```

Desearía poder hacer un sort pero dicho string no cuenta como un array.
Existe manera de transformarlo en Array?

del lado de javascript o C# ?

Comment: No es un JSON válido porque se queda una coma al final en cada propiedad de este tipo: `"ProductComment": "2|1|3",`.  Si corriges eso y le quitas las comillas simples de inicio y final puedes trabajar con el en javascript. Aquí un ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/9L5804c2/

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar con este codigo

```
string[] str = (string[])JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json,(typeof(string[])));
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente el funcionamiento del código. Lee [answer].